# can't build ionic project despite having JDK 1.8

Tags: android, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been given an ionic projekt via Git which i am trying to build on my windows with:

> ionic cordova build android --g

[But i get this error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFuO4.png)

As you can see in the image, i have set the environment variables and i have JDK 1.8 installed (not 4.0.0, as claimed in the error message).

[Here you can see the Android and java enviroment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlJX5.png)

[and thats how my paths look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/874Qq.png)

What am i missing? What do i have to to to be able to build this project?

Comment: Can you show us your environment variable?

Comment: i have added the enviroment variables to my question

Comment: I came across this also, what I did was just to uninstall everything using https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.html, reinstalled everything and made sure the path is correct.  The uninstaller also detects older versions of JDK that might be behind this error.